# browserhistory logged only with special browser

Tags: android, browser-history

Hi i have an app which reads the browserhistory with this code

```
String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0";
Cursor mCur = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, sel, null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
```

But it seems fom device to devie it logs only with one special browser:

```
s4 (4.2.2)=chrome
s5 (4.2.2)=chrome
htc one (4.2.2)=default browser
Samsung ace (4.1.2)=default browser
```

on what does it depend which browser logs it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that depends if a browser logs to Android built-in [Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) for the browser activity. Some browsers might, but not all of them do.

Usually the stock browser, the one that comes installed on the device, do. But there're no guarantees that others will.

Comment: But shouldn't chrome log into the content provider on all devices if it does it on one device? All have the latest update of chrome.

Comment: "should" is different than "do". I believe for proper organisation ALL browsers should. But point is: your code is correct, what's interfering with your results is out of your control.

Comment: but why does chrome log on a galaxy s5 but not on a htc one? Both have the same android version

Comment: I can guess that it might have something to do with signature protection, only system apps can write to the ContentProvider, but I didn't write Chrome browser code, I can't answer that. But it's open source, so you can try check there: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions